# Missing the SCRUM "backlog" and "board" tabs in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, scrum

I've installed TFS 2012 Express on Windows server 2008.
Created new project, and choose the Scrum 2.0 process template.

From all the tutorials, I understand that I am supposed to have **backlog**, **board** and **work items** tabs.
However, I have only the **work items**. How do I get the two others?

Here: [View Backlog link is missing from the TFS11 home page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFSvnext/thread/6712d988-4186-4367-980f-42e6f422c3b8/)
someone pointed that there is Web Access Permissions setting in the Administration page,
but in the Administration page, I am also missing the **web acess** tab.

Comment: What a bummer hey- I installed TFS too thinking I could use this even after it asked me during setup what templates I want to use.. **face slap**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Agile Planning tool are not available in TFS Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/07/visual-studio-2012-features-enabled-by-using-a-tfs-2012-server.aspx). Under the "Agile/Scrum" section of the post it says:

> Product Backlog and Sprint Planning – these require Premium or Ultimate (see this post about enabling via the [licensing feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/03/after-upgrading-updating-licensing-and-enabling-async-checkout-for-server-workspaces.aspx))

At the end of the article it also mentions:

> [UPDATE 6/7/2012]  [TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express) does not include any of the Agile features.  It is really focused on source control, build, and bug tracking.  You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide any documentation from MS about the unavailability of SCRUM in TFS Express?

Comment: You can find the information here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/06/07/visual-studio-2012-features-enabled-by-using-a-tfs-2012-server.aspx [UPDATE 6/7/2012]  TFS Express does not include any of the Agile features.  It is really focused on source control, build, and bug tracking.  You can read more about it here.